# Differntiable function prof

Tags: analysis

it is known that $f(0,0) = 0$ and $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$. It is also known that for every $t>0$ we have $f(\cos(t)/t , \sin(t)/t) > 0$.

Show that necessarily $\operatorname{Gradient}(0,0) = (0,0)$.

I have no clue how to solve this. I have tried to show through limits, I have tried to get something from the definition ( that with $\varepsilon, \:(x/y) \to 0$ at the limit)

Thank you for your cooperation

Comment: Anyone ? Can you please help